# Ember Not returning correct serialiser for model on calling store.serializerFor method

Tags: javascript, serialization, ember.js, ember-data

I have two models , record-type and record-type-choice, when I call store.serilizerFor or lookupserializer for on modal record-type-choice , the serializer for record-type is returned? can you guys help me with what I might be doing wrong?

model - record-type-choice

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  value: attr('string'),
  position: attr('number'),
  type: attr('string'),
  dependentIds: attr({
    defaultValue() {
      return {};
    }
  }),
  dependencyMappingId: attr('string'),
  editable: attr('boolean')

});
```

serializer record-type-choice

```
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  normalize(typeClass, hash, prop) {
    return this._super(typeClass, hash, prop);
  }
});
```

record-type model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  // recordTypeId: attr('number'),
  value: attr('string'),
  accessibleRoleIds: attr({ defaultValue: () => [] })
  // permissionStatus: attr('string'),
  // meta: attr()
});
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a reproduction? You could maybe use [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) to do so. Otherwise we would need at least enough code to reproduce ourselves. This means _at least_ the code for both models, both serializers, the application serializer and how you check if the correct serializer is returned by `Store.serializerFor()`. If omitting some code please verify that your issue could be still reproduced with only that subset.